# How to handle configuring many objects from an external file?

Tags: python

I've got JSON file which holds external settings which need to be set for objects inside my program. This leads to code that looks something like this:

```
a_settings = ASettings()
a = A(a_settings, <other dependencies>)
b_settings = BSettings()
b = B(b_settings, <other dependencies>)
c_settings = CSettings()
c = C(c_settings, <other dependencies>)
```

where each `XSettings()` reads from the settings file the values it needs, and then the constructor for `X` accesses them from the `x_settings` variable which was injected into it.

I'm pretty sure this is the wrong way to achieve this. Which better ways are there if there are any?

Clarification: The settings file is necessary since it holds values that need to be set externally but still need to be loaded into the program.

Edit: The JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "a": {
        "a1": "value1",
        "a2": "value2"
    },
    "b": {
        "b1": "value3",
        "b2": "value4"
    },
    "c": "value5"
}
```

Comment: Plese tell us more about the JSON files. Do they have a similar structure?

Comment: I'll edit and add an example

Comment: Is this *one* file for `A`, `B`, and `C`? Or does *each* file look like this?

Comment: It's one file. I guess I could break it up although I don't really see any benefit in doing so.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Please fix it and check it at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

`settings.json`:

```
{
    "a": {
        "a1": "value1",
        "a2": "value2"
    },
    "b": {
        "b1": "value3",
        "b2": "value4"
    },
    "c": "value5"
}
```

Python code:

```
import json

settings = json.load(open("settings.json"))
# {'a': {'a2': 'value2', 'a1': 'value1'}, 'b': {'b2': 'value4', 'b1': 'value3'}}
a = A(settings["a"])
b = B(settings["b"])
c = C(settings["c"])
```